# Is it possible to fit to a parametric curve in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

I would like to fit a data-set, given by an `n`-dimensional vector `data` (with values between -1 and 1 and with corresponding x-values `linspace(0,9,n)`), to the parametric curve given by

```
x = cos(t)/sqrt(1-(a/b)^2)
y = b*sin(t)-a
```

for `a < b` and `0 < t < pi`. This curve is the upper half of an ellipse that has been lowered `a` below the x-axis and which intersects the x-axis at -1 and 1. I'm fitting for the parameters `a,b`.

Writing this function on the form `y(x)`seems impossible (*edit: not the case, see comments - however, I would still like to know the answer to the following question:*) ... can fitting in Matlab be done from the parametric form? How?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you write your function as `y = @(x,a,b)b*sin(acos(x*sqrt(1 - (a/b)^2))) - a` . And since it can be written in this form you can use `fitnlm` to get the fit ?

Comment: @SomeGuy Hm, that might work, but I'm afraid that some weird stuff is going to happen, arising from principal values-messiness in the trig-functions.. Also, the information about the interval for `t` is lost in this way.. but thank you for the suggestion (if you find that it does indeed work, I'd be happy to accept that implementation as an answer)!

Comment: @SomeGuy I think it works... the expression reduces to `y = b*sqrt(1-x^2*(1-(a/b)^2))-a`, which seems to work. Thanks again. However, I think the question about whether or not parametric fitting is possible is still interesting in itself, so I'm going to leave it open for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your function in a `y = f(x)` format and then use `fitnlm` to estimate parameters for your non-linear model.

```
fh = @(x,a,b)b*sin(acos(x*sqrt(1 - (a/b)^2))) - a % Define y = f(x)
x = [-1:0.01:1]; % Generate some x values
yval = fh(x,1,2); % Calculate y values for the x 
yval_ = yval + 0.1*rand(1,201); % Add artifical noise

nonLinMdl = fitnlm(x,yval_,@(p,x)fh(x,p(1),p(2)),[1.5, 2.5])

nonLinMdl = 


Nonlinear regression model:
    y ~ y(x,p1,p2)

Estimated Coefficients:
          Estimate       SE       tStat       pValue  
          ________    ________    ______    __________

    p1    0.71909     0.053201    13.516    5.8209e-30
    p2     1.7668     0.055472    31.849    4.6625e-80


Number of observations: 201, Error degrees of freedom: 199
Root Mean Squared Error: 0.032
R-Squared: 0.988,  Adjusted R-Squared 0.988
F-statistic vs. zero model: 6.36e+04, p-value = 5.87e-280
```

Note that the parameters calculated are different from what we used `(1,2)`. This might have to do something with the fact that the function shape is the same for a different set of parameters. You could also try different starting points.

```
ycalc = fh(x,nonLinMdl.Coefficients.Estimate('p1'),nonLinMdl.Coefficients.Estimate('p2'))
plot(x,yval_,x,ycalc)
```

I cannot upload files since I am in a restricted environment but I plotted both series and the model calculated values were pretty close to the input data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, if you plot the function with the chosen values and the found values, they differ. I do believe `fh(x)` can be proven to be injective, so they should differ. However, when only a limited amount of points is used (or the noise is large), I can see how different sets of parameters could fit equally well. Hopefully this won't be a problem in this particular case.